# test hardware interface without hardware

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

is it possible to test hardware interfce code without using the actual hardwre at the time?
currently i tired this code but its not workign at all:

```
#include <hardware_interface/joint_command_interface.h>
#include <hardware_interface/joint_state_interface.h>
#include <hardware_interface/robot_hw.h>
#include <controller_manager/controller_manager.h>

class ROBOTHardwareInterface : public hardware_interface::RobotHW
{
public:
  ROBOTHardwareInterface() 
 { 
   // connect and register the joint state interface
   hardware_interface::JointStateHandle state_handle_a("joint1", &pos[0], &vel[0], &eff[0]);
   jnt_state_interface.registerHandle(state_handle_a);

   hardware_interface::JointStateHandle state_handle_b("joint2", &pos[1], &vel[1], &eff[1]);
   jnt_state_interface.registerHandle(state_handle_b);

   hardware_interface::JointStateHandle state_handle_c("joint3", &pos[2], &vel[2], &eff[2]);
   jnt_state_interface.registerHandle(state_handle_c);

   registerInterface(&jnt_state_interface);

   // connect and register the joint position interface
   hardware_interface::JointHandle pos_handle_a(jnt_state_interface.getHandle("joint1"), &cmd[0]);
   jnt_pos_interface.registerHandle(pos_handle_a);

   hardware_interface::JointHandle pos_handle_b(jnt_state_interface.getHandle("joint2"), &cmd[1]);
   jnt_pos_interface.registerHandle(pos_handle_b);

   hardware_interface::JointHandle pos_handle_c(jnt_state_interface.getHandle("joint3"), &cmd[2]);
   jnt_pos_interface.registerHandle(pos_handle_c);

   registerInterface(&jnt_pos_interface);
  }

  void read() { std::cout<<"read"<<std::endl; };
  void write() { std::cout<<"write"<<std::endl; };
  ros::Time get_time() {
      ros::Time t = ros::Time::now();
      return t; 
  }
  ros::Duration get_period() {
      ros::Duration duration(1);
      return duration; 
  }

private:
  hardware_interface::JointStateInterface jnt_state_interface;
  hardware_interface::PositionJointInterface jnt_pos_interface;
  double cmd[3];
  double pos[3];
  double vel[3];
  double eff[3];
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    ros::init(argc, argv, "robot_hardware_interface");
    ros::NodeHandle nh;

    ROBOTHardwareInterface robot;
    controller_manager::ControllerManager cm(&robot);

    while (true)
    {
        robot.read();
        cm.update(robot.get_time(), robot.get_period());
        robot.write();
        sleep(1);
    }
}
```

configuration file -----------------
three_dof_planar_manipulator:
# Publish all joint states -----------------------------------
joints_update:
type: joint_state_controller/JointStateController
publish_rate: 50

```
    # Position Controllers ---------------------------------------
    joint1:
      type: position_controllers/JointPositionController
      joint: joint1
      pid: {p: 1.0, i: 1.0, d: 0.0}
    joint2:
      type: position_controllers/JointPositionController
      joint: joint2
      pid: {p: 1.0, i: 1.0, d: 0.0}
    joint3:
      type: position_controllers/JointPositionController
      joint: joint3
      pid: {p: 1.0, i: 1.0, d: 0.0}
```

launch file ----------------

```
  <rosparam file="$(find three_dof_planar_manipulator)/config/controllers.yaml" command="load"/>
   
  <arg name="model" default="$(find three_dof_planar_manipulator)/urdf/three_dof_planar_manipulator.urdf.xacro"/>
  <arg name="gui" default="true" />
  
  <param name="robot_description" command="$(find xacro)/xacro.py $(arg model)" />
  <param name="use_gui" value="$(arg gui)"/>

  <node name="robot_hardware_interface" pkg="three_dof_planar_manipulator" type="robot_hardware_interface" output="screen"/>

  <node name="robot_state_publisher" pkg="robot_state_publisher" type="state_publisher" >
  </node>
  
  <node name="rviz" pkg="rviz" type="rviz"/>
    
  <node name="controller_spawner" pkg="controller_manager" type="spawner" respawn="false" output="screen"
        args="
            /three_dof_planar_manipulator/joints_update
            /three_dof_planar_manipulator/joint1
            /three_dof_planar_manipulator/joint2
            /three_dof_planar_manipulator/joint3
        "/>
</launch>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/347896/test-hardware-interface-without-hardware/) by [dinesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/26847/dinesh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 932 on 2020-03-30

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-03-31**:
pedantic, but:

> i tired this code but its not workign at all:

Please don't "tire" us by not telling us what "does not work" actually means.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-03-31**:
Also: is this not a duplicate of #q347800?

If it is: please don't post duplicates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ok. finally after testing, dubugging, modifying and searchign through internet finally i found a good source/link to learn hardware interface in [this](https://github.com/PickNikRobotics/ros_control_boilerplate) page without depending on external hardware libraries and hardware.

---

Originally posted by [dinesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/26847/dinesh/) with karma: 932 on 2020-03-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0